# Implicit casting of an object to string, for use in a Hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable, implicit-conversion

Let's say we have this class:

```
public class Moo
{
    string _value;

    public Moo(string value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Moo x)
    {
        return x._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Moo(string x)
    {
        return new Moo(x);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is string)
            return this._value == obj.ToString();
        else if (obj is Moo)
            return this._value == ((Moo)obj)._value;
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If I add an object of this type to a Hashtable, then I can find the object using the identical string.
But if the Hashtable contains the string not the object, it fails to find it when I pass the object.

```
Moo moo = new Moo("abc");
bool result1 = moo == "abc";                    //true
bool result1a = moo.Equals("abc");              //true
bool result2 = "abc" == moo;                    //true
bool result2a = "abc".Equals(moo);              //true
bool result2b = ((object)"abc").Equals(moo);    //false

Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
hash[moo] = 100;
object result3 = hash[moo];                     //100
object result4 = hash["abc"];                   //100

hash = new Hashtable();
hash["abc"] = 100;
object result5 = hash[moo];                     //null!!!!
object result6 = hash["abc"];                   //100
```

I've tried overriding operator== and it made no difference.
Is it possible to use implicit casting in a Hashtable in this way?

Comment: You're violating one of the essential properties of Equals: "x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, why are you using a hashtable rather than a generic `Dictionary<,>`?

Regardless, your problem is that the hashtable is calling `((object)"abc").Equals(moo)`, which returns false, of course.  You can override that behavior by passing your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer` to one of the `HashTable` constructors with an `IEqualityComparer` parameter.

Since, as you've noted, you are trying to avoid modifying legacy code, it may be that you are unable to replace the existing hash table with one that has a custom IEqualityComparer.  If that's true, then I think the answer is that you can't do what you would like to do.

Since you're developing this "moo" class, I suppose you have control over the code that passes the moo class to the hash table's indexer.  If that's true, you could just call `ToString()` on the object you're passing to the indexer, and of course, override `ToString` in `Moo`.

Comment: Nope, "abc".Equals(moo) returns true. And I'm stuck using the Hashtable because I'm trying to change legacy code without having to, er, change the code.

Comment: `"abc".Equals(moo)` returns true for me. If you assign `moo` to an `object` instance though - `"abc".Equals(mooObj)` returns false.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: `"abc".Equals(moo)` only returns true because the compiler is performing the operator overload - which it knows about *at compile-time*. Try `((object)"abc").Equals(moo)` to see what the Hashtable will do.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `((object)"abc").Equals(moo)` does indeed return false.

Comment: why not just overload the toString method and let the thing compare a pair of strings.  String already has a comparison overload that takes an object and uses it's to string method.

Note, I'm not sure if the hash table would grab the tostring or not.

Comment: You must use `IEqualityComparer<T>` (or if you insist on using legacy collections its non generic equivalent). You can't use `Equals`, since it **must** be symmetrical, or you get undefined behavior when using equality based collections.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey yes, `"abc".Equals(moo)` uses the implicit moo-to-string conversion and calls the `Equals(string)` overload.  I typed that as a shortcut for what's really happening, which as others noted, is the hash table is calling the `Equals(object)` overload, because it has an object-type reference to the string.  I edited the answer to include the `(object)` cast that forces the "correct" overload to be selected.

Comment: You're right, it appears the answer to my problem is "I can't quite do that". Although I was trying to be sneaky and avoid changing any code, some code change is necessary. The simplest code change is to change each `Hashtable` to use the `IEqualityComparer` constructor, and as you and others have said, to create a custom comparer from my Moo.Equals method. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

So the implicit casts there are irrelevant.  They won't do a thing.  You'll get exactly the same results if you comment them out.  What matters here is the Equals and GetHashCode methods.

So your GetHashCode method is fine.  Two objects (whether it's a string or a moo) will always have the same hash if they should be the same, so it will work.  Your problem is with your equals method.

`moo.Equals("abc")` will return true.

```
object obj = moo;
"abc".Equals(obj)
```

will return false;
 `"abc".Equals(moo)` will return true only because there is an implicit operator that converts moo into a string, and uses the string overload of `Equals`, rather than the object overload of `Equals`.  Since the Hashtable is going to store everything as an object, it will always be using the `object` overload of the `Equals` method.  (The == operator isn't used; it uses the `Equals` method within dictionary.)  This is because the string's `Equals` method will check to make sure that the object passed in is a string, and it will return false if its not.

The solution:
You need to not use the default constructor of HashTable.  What you need to do is use a custom `IEqualityComparor` so that it doesn't use the `Equals` method of the object itself.  This is not too hard to do.  Just make a new class that extends `IEqualityComparer` and give it an equals method that is basically the same as your moo's `Equals` method so that it will perform the comparison properly regardless of which type either object it.

Comment: Nope, "abc".Equals(moo) returns true I'm afraid.

Comment: Then that's because of the implicit conversion, which won't be possible with a hashtable.  `object obj = moo; "abc".Equals(obj)` will return false

Comment: I've expanded the answer to incorporate a better explanation of what calls to `Equals` is doing.